# Loop - Input numbers to list, don't allow alphabetic input, break out by pressing enter ..?

Tags: python, python-2.7

been at this all day and made absolutely no progress, it's surely supposed to be pretty simple too but I'm new to Python. Google hasn't brought up much so this is my last resort!

It's supposed to be some basic code for manually putting numeric values into a list. If I add a 'print' line to the script I can see the values are being successfully entered as I go along, but I can't seem to add the right script for breaking out of the loop by leaving the input blank. Currently if I set anything to make it break, the script seems to freeze while it's running and I have to reset the console completely.

Also I'm wondering is there a way of ensuring the input is always an integer? It would be good to make things a bit cleaner and bring up an error message or something if the user enters anything non-numeric.

Here's the code.

```
values = []
while True:
    a = raw_input('Enter numeric values. Leave blank to stop: ')
    if a == (??????) :
        break
values.append(float(a))
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you could make a an string you could do something like:
if(a=="") and in an else clause turn the string into a float value

Answer (score 4):

You can restrict to only numbers with

```
if a.isdigit():
```

So your function could look like

```
def accept_inputs():
    values = []
    while True:     
        a = raw_input('Enter numeric values. Leave blank to stop: ')
        if a.isdigit():
            values.append(float(a))
        if not a:
            return values
```

Testing

```
>>> accept_inputs()
Enter numeric values. Leave blank to stop: 5
Enter numeric values. Leave blank to stop: 42
Enter numeric values. Leave blank to stop: 73
Enter numeric values. Leave blank to stop: ab
Enter numeric values. Leave blank to stop: abc
Enter numeric values. Leave blank to stop: 
[5, 42, 73]
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings have a built in function `isdigit()` that returns true if all the characters are numbers.

To break out if nothing is entered, use the `len()` function to detect if the string is empty.

[More info here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

You're code would look like this:

```
 if a.isdigit():
     #keep going, and add it to the list
 elif len(a) == 0:
        break #stop the loop
```

Comment: A more robust solution would be to use `isdigit`. Because things like punctuation will get past `isalpha` but are not valid digits and will throw exceptions when trying to convert to `float`

Answer (score 0):

My approach is similar to @CoryKramer, with small changes

```
>>> values = []
>>> while True:
       val = raw_input('Enter Number : ')
       if not val:
          print values
       elif val.isdigit():
          values.append(int(val))
       else:
          print 'you have entered non - digit value'

Enter Number : 2
Enter Number : a
you have entered non - digit value
Enter Number : 3
Enter Number : 5
Enter Number : 6
Enter Number : 22
Enter Number : 546
Enter Number : 31s
you have entered non - digit value
Enter Number : 345678
Enter Number : 
>>> values
[2, 3, 5, 6, 22, 546, 345678]
```